# Not able to understand how select_tag working in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code in rails,

```
<%= select_tag 'profile', (options_from_collection_for_select(@profiles, :id, :name, @dealer.profileid.to_i))%>
```

And it is generating like following html,

```
<select id="profile" name="profile">         
  <option value="CM Profile">CM Profile</option>   
  <option value="Admin Profile">Admin Profile</option>     
 </select>
```

But i want value in option tag should be "id" of profiles object. But it is assigining name of `@profile object`.

And schema of profile table is,

```
id ==> int(11) ==> auto_increment       

name ==> varchar(20) ==> primary key      

type ==> int(11)
```

How can i do it ??

Answer (score 0):

According to [syntax](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

```
<%= select_tag 'profile', (options_from_collection_for_select(@profiles, :id, :name, @dealer.profileid.to_i))%>
```

is right, It should work as you intend to.

---

Unless your syntax is something like this

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@profiles, :name, :name, @dealer.profileid.to_i)
```

will produce

```
<select id="profile" name="profile">         
  <option value="CM Profile">CM Profile</option>   
  <option value="Admin Profile">Admin Profile</option>     
 </select>
```

Comment: :My question is clear. This same code is working when i am fetching data from other table. But for this it not working.

will it depends upon table schema or based on syntax like we have
:id ,:name in syntax.

Comment: how does schema involve here? It has nothing to do. Syntax is tried out, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use options_for_select and manually form options

```
<%=select_tag "profile", options_for_select(@profiles.map{|p| [p.name,p.id]})%>
```

Comment: I change it, try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers didn't solved my problem. But when changed my code it worked for me.
Change is,

Previously i wrote code like

```
@profile = Profile.select("id ,name").where("dealertype = ?","2").all
```

when i iterate this object and printed id and name both are coming same.

Now i modified to,

```
@profile = Profile.select("id as profileid,name").where("dealertype = ?","2").all
```

Now in this case, when i iterate this object and printed id and name, values coming proper
unlike above code.

Now in `select_tag`,

```
<%= select_tag 'profile', (options_from_collection_for_select(@profiles, :profileid, :name, @dealer.profileid.to_i))%>
```

instead of `id` changed to `profileid`.

Now it is working fine,

```
  <select id="profile" name="profile">         
       <option value="1">CM Profile</option>   
       <option value="2">Admin Profile</option>     
   </select>
```

But don't know exactly when i am iterating,

```
@profile = Profile.select("id ,name").where("dealertype = ?","2").all
```

both id and name values coming same.